# How to print largest number from User Input

Tags: c++, input, addition

I am to let the user input how many floating number he wants to type in. Once the floating numbers are typed in I am to have a message that says something like "The largest number you inputted is so and so".

How do I recognizing the largest number inputted by the user.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    float count; 
    float input; 
    float large; 

    cout << "Enter the number of floating numbers you wish to input: ";
    scanf("%f", &count); 

    do
    {
        cin >> input; 
        count--; 

    }
    while(0 < count); 

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Didn't you're instructor covered the basics of `if` statements and comparison operators?

Comment: He did cover the if statements. I have tried multiple variations of it but I am not sure if to include the if statement inside the do-while loop or outside the do while loop . I tried making the variable largest so that I could put largest = input; but this will be overwritten every time a user puts their floating number. Which essentially is not what I am trying to accomplish

Comment: This is not a coding service and you aren't going to learn unless you do it yourself. Instead you need to _try something_, explain what you expected it should do, explain how it's not doing what you expected, and ask a specific question to fix that specific issue.

Comment: `if` a greater value is inputted than `max` set `max` to that value (inside of the loop)

Comment: @Jane Apparently you don´t understand. You **should not** destroy your question. Rolled back, 3th time total. Flag is still pending...

Comment: **Moderator note**: as @deviantfan has noted - please desist in removing the content of your question - it invalidates answers and isn't fair to future visitors or those who have spent their time answering. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method is quick and clean, basically read in values the number of times specified, and each time the number is greater than the current maximum, replace max with the value read.

```
    int main()
    {
        int num_entries;
        float num;
        float max = 0;
        cin >> num_entries;
        while (num_entries-- > 0){
            cin >> num;
            if (num > max) {
                max = num;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This helped tremendously. Thank you Jack Ryan! I ended up keeping the it the way I had it written but I realized how to resolve my issue through the way you wrote the max in your code. Thank you!

Comment: I actually just realized that this solution may not work if all of your input numbers are negative, instead you might try initializing max to the minimum float value.

Answer (score 1):

Here is example with "for" loop

```
int main()
{
    int conut = 0;
    float number = 0;
    float max_number = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i != count; ++i)
    {
         cin >> number; // the user input
         if (number > max_number) max_number = number; // if input is  highter than actuall the highest number then max_number = number
    }

    std::cout << "max_number = " << max_number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int input1;
    List<Integer> mylist = new ArrayList<>();
    while (true){
        input1 =sc.nextInt();
        if (input1!=0){
            mylist.add(input1);
        }  else{
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(mylist);
    int max = mylist.get(0);
    for (int i = 0; i <mylist.size() ; i++) {
        if (mylist.get(i)>max){
            max = mylist.get(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(max + " Is the maximum number");
```